# (VBA) Why won't my DateValue function trim off the time for some rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm just manipulating some of my step data throughout the year, but I'm seriously wondering where I've gone wrong with the date function. Why does the DateValue function work the way I want up until row 2804? After that point, it just keeps the "0:00" along with the date.

The data in column A looks the same throughout the entire spreadsheet, so I'm not sure where else to dig around, and if anyone has encountered this before.

[image: Sample step counter export data]

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Range, lastRow As Integer, rw As Integer
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Set x = Range("B2:B" & lastRow)

    For Each cell In x
        rw = cell.Row
        cell.Value = Format(DateValue(Range("A" & rw).Value), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: The time portion has been trimmed off, though. Instead of using `Format`, change the cell's `NumberFormat`. That said, `lastRow` and `rw` should be `Long` instead of `Integer`, and there are more robust ways to find the last row.

Comment: @BigBen how would you suggest fixing up how to define the lastRow variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're doing is changing number formatting (*which doesn't at all discard the time portion of the date*), perhaps something like the following:

```
Sub Test()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    End With
End Sub
```

Or format the whole column in one go, as suggested by @Comintern:

```
Sub Test
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the NumberFormat function suggested by @BigBen instead, I was able to cut out quite a bit more code and not have to bother with creating a new column

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        cell.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: If that's all you're doing, you don't need a loop. `Range("A2:A" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"`

Comment: @Comintern even better.